# convert at symbol ("@") to CharSequence

Tags: java, selenium, charsequence

I am testing site with selenium and I need to send an e-mail to one of the fields. So far I am using this Java method:

```
 String email = "test@example.com"
 WebElement emailField = driver.findElement(By.id("mainForm:accountPanelTabId:1:accountEmails");
 emailField.sendKeys(email);
```

But from (to me) uknown reason, this is sending exactly this value to the field:

```
testvexample.com
```

(so basically the "@" got replaced by "v")

Just out of curiosity: I am Czech and have Czech keyboard. One shortcut to write "@" symbol is rightAlt + v so I believe this can be connected...

So I am searching any "bulletproof" methot which always writes "@" symbol. Any help appreciated.

**EDIT**
the sendKeys is method of Selenium, and it simulates typing on keyboard. The javadoc is here: http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#sendKeys%28java.lang.CharSequence...%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>The following should work: `String email = "test\u0040example.com";`</strike>

Apologies for misreading the question earlier.

I think you will have to call `sendKeys` using the proper values from the `Keys` enum to simulate the way you get your at-sign.  Use `Keys.ALT` with your "v" in a chord:

```
sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.ALT, "v"));
```

Comment: bad news... still the same :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  That means the `sendKeys` method is doing something to your string.  And here I was thinking that you had a strange font. ;-)  Can you get to the source code for `sendKeys`?

Comment: Javadoc is here: http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#sendKeys%28java.lang.CharSequence...%29

Comment: Got me to the solution: When I changed my keyboard defaults from "Czech" to "English" (so now, the English Keyboard is the default one), the original code started working. Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Late to party, but right combination is Keys.chord(Keys.ALT, Keys.CONTROL, "v"), as rightAlt usually works like ALT+CTRL.