# Force keyboard layout for Selenium2 sendkeys method

Tags: selenium

Is it somehow possible to force Selenium2 webdriver sendkeys method to use specific keyboard layout instead of Windows active one in specific testcase?

The issue I ran into is that my default keyboard layout is "Latvian (apostrophe)" (where apostrophe is pressed before accented letters) and

```
webdriver.findElement(By.name("lastName")).sendKeys("O'Neill");
```

is actually entered as "OŅeill" in the field.

P.S. Couldn't find one, but maybe there's some Selenium2 webdriver method for setting field value as a whole without typing?

Answer (score 0):

I did not found any solution also. So my solution actually is, that layout default in my system is English and for specific applications (mail) I switch my keyboard manually to layout which I need (Czech in my case)

See my question here on SO: [convert at symbol ("@") to CharSequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186474/convert-at-symbol-to-charsequence)

I accepted an answer which was providing good hint for workaround, but it was not working 100%